# Sklearn predict function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikits

I am using `sklearn`'s Linear Regression ML model in Python to predict. The `predict` function returns an `array` with a lot of floating point numbers, (which is correct) but I don't quite understand what the floating point numbers represent. Is it possible to map them back?

For context, I am trying to predict sales of a product (label) from stocks available. The predict function returns a large array of floating point numbers. How do I know what each floating point number represents?

For instance, the array is like [11.5, 12.0, 6.1,..]. It seems 6.1 is the sales qty but with what stock quantity is it associated with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'th output is prediction for i'th input. Whatever you passed to .predict is a collection of objects, and the ordering of predictions is the same as the ordering of data passed in.

Comment: Thank you. So just to confirm, if I have output = predict(features) then output[i] will be the predicted value of features[i]?